# Forcing UIButton to have just one title line

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, title

I'm trying to force the UIButton to accept just one line of text, and if the title is too long I would like to have "..." at the end or in the middle of the title. but when I try out the code below, unfortunately, it doesn't work, it still gives multiline title text.

```
titleButton.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
titleButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
titleButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem was the button style which was on the "plain", the magic happened after changing it to default!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want `lineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail` or `.byTruncatingMiddle`.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, seems like the main problem was the button style which was on the "plain", the magic happened after changing it to default!

Comment: Saved my day. changing to "Default" from "Plain" was the issue

Comment: Why the downvote? Two commenters found my answer helpful. If my answer is wrong or deficient in some way I'd like to know about it so I can improve it, but "drive by downvotes" drive me crazy.